# pass UNiqueIdentifier to another asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have coded this page  [image]

I need to pass the uniqueidentifier to another page, i have try these ways :

```
e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "<a href='Clientes.aspx?UserName='>" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "</a>";
```

and this

```
 Response.Redirect("~/Clientes.aspx?Nome=" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
```

what the best and secure way to pass the GUID to another page ???
Thanks 
Alejandro Carnero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this way , source page :

```
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="False" 
        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="770px" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
      <asp:HyperLinkField Text="Mostrar Cadastro"  DataNavigateUrlFields="idcliente"
       DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Clientes.aspx?ID={0}"
       />          
      <asp:BoundField DataField="idcliente"  HeaderText="ID"   />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="nome" HeaderText="Nome"    />     
      <asp:BoundField DataField="endere" HeaderText="Endereço" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Tel" HeaderText="Telefone" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="pedido" HeaderText="Pedido" />
```

Destiny page :

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       LblIDCliente.Text  = Request.QueryString["ID"];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the codebehind of your first page, store the unique identifier in a Session variable, and then redirect to the "Clients" page normally:

```
Session["myUniqueID"] = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
Response.Redirect("~/Clientes.aspx");
```

Then, in the codebehind of "Clientes.aspx", retreive it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myUniqueID = Session["myUniqueID"].ToString();
}
```

*Note: I use "Page_Load" as an example, you could put this code in whatever method you want.*

Comment: jadarnel27 : I haves try this way  only pass <a href='Clientes.aspx'>&nbsp;</a> i need to pass the Guid information

Comment: I have updated my answer to try to be more clear, @alejandro.  Does that make more sense?